# Hide new "play" icon in menu bar after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: big-sur

I recently upgraded to Big Sur and I now have a media player icon which I don't really use or need. Is there any way to hide it?

It's the far left icon in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Apple is really good at giving people annoying nonsense they don't need or want.  The idea that I have to come find this question on SO to figure out how to disable something like this is ridiculous

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can hide the "play" icon in the menu bar as follows:

1. Launch System Preferences.
2. Open Dock & Menu Bar.
3. Scroll down and select "Now Playing".
4. The "Show in Menu Bar" option controls whether the "play" icon is displayed

   [image]

   **Unselect it to hide it for good, or change the value to "when active" to only display it when playing music.**

Comment: Is there a way to remove it from Control Center?

Comment: @MatthewRead Well, System Preferences doesn't offer any control to remove it, and I don't know of any command that can achieve that. You may want to post a question though, someone may have the answer you are looking for...

Comment: It worked in MonTerey MacOS also. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried both this and the item below and the icon immediately re-appears.

Comment: is there a way to select which apps should be in the list after clicking the button? i have spotify and MS Teams, and when I press the play button (F8) it plays ringing sound of ms teams which is pretty annoying :D

Comment: @hocikto Good question, not that I know of...

Comment: About my question - I found out that BeardedSpice app is working quite good as a replacement for the default Media button

Answer (score 9):

You can also ⌘+click and drag it off the bar.